# Basic draw method blenddstate not recognized?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, draw, alphablending

I am pretty good at programming, however, i am new to c# (xna), i am following a tutorial to draw a sprite on screen and the blendstate method is not recognized when used like the following in the draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            // Draw the sprite.
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

//doesnt recognize blendstate (puts squiggles under it)

```
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, spritePosition, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

thanks in advance as this is definately bothering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is: What happens if you mouse-over the error? It should give you a tool-tip with the text telling you what the actual error is.

Additionally, if you haven't got `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics` at the top of your source file (but you *have* got Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll referenced by the project, which you also need), it will also give you a little box to click to add in that using statement (I believe the shortcut key to make it pop up is Ctrl-Shift-F10).

Also you could just pass in `null` instead of `BlendState.AlphaBlend`, as that is the default blend state (see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433698.aspx)).

---

My *second* thought is that you're using an XNA 4.0 tutorial with an older version of XNA. Are you? [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) explains the differences in SpriteBatch.

Comment: I do have the code using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics at the top of my code, however, i could not find anything saying that i had that reference implemented. How would i do this? i right-click on references and click new reference and i double-click Microsoft.Xna.Framework and it doesnt help.

The error(when i mouse-over the error) is this: 


Error 1 The name 'Blendstate' does not exist in the current context

thank you, and ps, when i put 'BlendState.AlphaBlend' as 'null', it gives me this error:

Error 1 No overload for method 'Begin' takes '2' arguments

Comment: @Custard: I have updated my answer. I think your XNA versions are mismatched.

Comment: @AndrewRussell

What is the Blendstate alternative for xna 3.1?

Comment: @RickardB **XNA 3.1 and earlier only:** For `SpriteBatch`, you simply provide a `SpriteBlendMode` to `Begin` and it sets things for you. Otherwise, `GraphicsDevice.RenderState` provides access to the various parts of the blend state via the following properties: `AlphaBlendEnable`, `AlphaBlendOperation`, `SourceBlend`, `DestinationBlend`, `SeparateAlphaBlend` (and maybe others). (Recommend updating to XNA 4.0, though, if possible. The state objects are really nice.)